# Binomial expansion for negative/fractional powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We learned today how to expand a binomials to a negative/fractional power. However, I'm not fully understanding the topic. Why is it that when you find the expansion of $(1+x)^{\frac{a}{b}}, \frac{a}{b}<1$ it's said that the expansion is convergent when $|x|<1$?

Firstly, what does the word **convergent** actually mean?

Second, what does the statement **$|x|<1$** mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably pose the questions in the opposite order, but let me answer them as you have posed them:

- *convergent*  means that if you evaluate the given power series for any $x$ in that range, you obtain a well defined (real) number
- $|x|<1$ means all numbers whose absolute value is strictly less than $1$. Examples are $-0.8,0,0.5,0.77899..$. Non-Examples are: $-5,-1,1,2,4,8$